# Cocoa PODs install failed

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

I tried to reinstall cocoa, delete workspace, nothing helped. What can it be ? I have checked all my paths: everything is alright. Yesterday everything was alright...

````
  16:57:28 Downloading dependencies
   16:57:28 Using MFSideMenu (0.5.4)
  16:57:28 Using MNCalendarView (0.0.2)
  16:57:28 Using MTDates (0.12.0)
  16:57:28 Using ROADFramework (1.3.4)
 16:57:28 Using libObjCAttr (1.3.0)
  16:57:28 Generating Pods project
  16:57:28 
   16:57:28 ‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï MARKDOWN TEMPLATE  ‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï‚Äï

    16:57:28    CocoaPods : 0.33.1
  16:57:28         Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
 16:57:28     RubyGems : 2.2.2
   16:57:28         Host : Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
   16:57:28        Xcode : 5.1.1 (5B1008)
   16:57:28 Ruby lib dir : /Users/epadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib
    16:57:28 Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @  ab93f17d0f57b40dcac3d01f066636f0567e5a6e
      16:57:28 ```
       16:57:28 
          16:57:28 platform :ios, '7.0'

  16:57:28 pod 'MFSideMenu', '~> 0.5'
    16:57:28 pod 'ROADFramework', '~> 1.3'
  16:57:28 pod 'MNCalendarView', :podspec => 'MNCalendarView.podspec'
   6:57:28 pod 'MTDates'

     16:57:28 LoadError - cannot load such file -- /Users/epadmin/jenkins-slave/workspace/AERL-MOBL-           IOS/AerLingus/Pods/libObjCAttr/libObjCAttr/Resources/ROADConfigurator.rb
````

here is my Podfile, mayube it will help smth

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MFSideMenu', '~> 0.5'
pod 'ROADFramework', '~> 1.3'
pod 'MNCalendarView', :podspec => 'MNCalendarView.podspec'
pod 'MTDates'

# ROADFramework generator and logging setup
post_install do |installer|
require File.expand_path('ROADConfigurator.rb', './Pods/libObjCAttr/libObjCAttr/Resources/')
ROADConfigurator::post_install(installer)
installer.project.targets.each do |target|
if (target.name == 'Pods-ROADFramework')
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if (config.name == 'Debug')
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = '$(inherited) DEBUG=1 ROAD_LOGGING_NSLOG     ROAD_LOGGING_LEVEL_INFO ROAD_LOGGING_SERIALIZATION_DISABLED'
    end
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post your `Podfile`?

Comment: certainly, will attach it main post